# Vimscript: what's the point of 'abort' in a function definition?

Tags: vim

In vimscript, `function` definitions can take an `abort` argument. To quote the docs,

```
When the [abort] argument is added, the function will
abort as soon as an error is detected
```

This leads me to seriously question what exactly functions normally do when they encounter errors. Stumble blindly forth into the darkness?

What does `abort` actually do? Does it break all of the `try...endtry` blocks? When do you want to use it, and when do you want to avoid it?

Comment: There is some specific discussion at [`*except-compat*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#except-compat).

Comment: I would say your intuition is correct though; in every other programming language as far as I know, aborting on errors is the default, and you have to explicitly `try catch` if you don't want that. Viml is the only odd duck here, and also the vint linter just wants you to put abort on every function always, which seems like good advice.

Comment: Well, shell scripts also don't abort on error (i.e., a command producing a non-zero exit code), by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As glts mentioned, all the complex details are documented at `:help except-compat`, and the answer basically boils down to backwards compatibility and the inherent flexibility of Vimscript.

There's a natural progression from recorded macros to mappings to custom functions. With that in mind, it may make sense that when a command in a function causes an error (e.g. a `%s/foo/bar/` that is not matching and missing the `e` flag), processing should continue.

On the other hand, when you write "industrial-grade" mappings, you'll almost always use a `try..catch` block inside your function call hierarchy, anyway (to avoid any multiline-errors `Error detected while processing function: ...`, and instead show a nice error message to the user).

So in practice, most published plugins do not use `abort`, but `try..catch`, and for quick, off-the-cuff stuff, you typically don't care too much about error handling, anyway.

Comment: Interesting. So as I understand it, functions proceed after errors unless in `try..endtry` or in a function with `abort`. So if you want helper functions to propagate exceptions up to the function that does the `catch`, must all of those helpers have `abort`?

Comment: No. Once inside a `try` block, the behavior changes, also for nested functions.