# Do Vim scripts have a way to halt on any error?

Tags: vim, error-handling

A simple example:

```
function! Foo()
    echom 'Starting Foo'
    let x = Bar(123)  " Function does not exist so E117 occurs.
    echom 'Nonetheless, this executes.'
endfunction
```

Does Vim have a mechanism to abort a function or script if any error
occurs -- in other words, something similar in spirit to this setting in `bash`?

```
set -o errexit
```

To clarify, I understand how to wrap error-prone code in `try-catch`. I'm
looking for a general mechanism to get Vim scripts to behave similar
to languages like Python, Ruby, Perl, and so forth, where an unhandled error
causes execution to screech to a halt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR

Always tag functions with `abort`

---

Your question has a recent duplicate on vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29038/how-do-i-make-a-function-stop-when-an-error-occurs/29039#29039
or, on the same topic: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/when-should-a-function-not-be-defined-with-abort

on SO, there are some more explanations regarding `abort`: [Vimscript: what's the point of 'abort' in a function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425648/vimscript-whats-the-point-of-abort-in-a-function-definition)